# Command line tool to Screenshot multiple monitors separately

Tags: command-line-interface, screenshot, multiple-monitors, xrandr

**Problem-statement**

I use `scrot` to take screenshots, which works perfectly except when I have multiple monitors or displays. In that case `scrot` joins the screenshots of different monitors into one single output.

From the manpage, `scrot` supports an option `-m`:

```
-m, --multidisp
        For multiple heads, grab shot from each and join them together.
```

So I imagined the default behavior would be to **NOT** join them together. However this is not the case. Even without the `-m` option I get joined screenshots.

I am optimistic that `scrot` should be able to do this as it support the `-u` option:

```
-u, --focused
        Use the currently focused window.
```

which works perfectly fine.

I also checked out another CLI tool called `maim` - but again I couldn't figure out how to take screenshot of different monitors separately.

So the solution I am excepting should work something like this:

```
screenshot_command <display_name> # and other options
```

to screenshot only the display `<display_name>`.

**My attempts at solution so far**

`maim` supports the curios looking option `-x`:

```
-x, --xdisplay=hostname:number.screen_number
          Sets the xdisplay to use.
```

So I tried `maim -x 0.0 | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png`, but that doesn't work. I don't know how this option is intended to be used as there isn't enough documentation.

Both `scrot` and `maim` also supports the option `-s`:

```
-s, --select
        Interactively select a window or rectangle with the mouse.
```

So I am imagining a very *ugly/ hacky* solution using `xdotool` (or similar) to select the desired display and using with the option `-s` to `maim` or `scrot` may do the job. But I would rather not tread this route unless there is no other straight forward solution.

**A wild speculation**

I wonder if this problem could be because of how I am adding new monitors? I usually add my second display with a command something like this:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --output HDMI-1-4 --auto --right-of eDP-1
```

So I am wondering, may be to `scrot` or `maim` there is *only one* display. And I imagine so because the output of `xdpyinfo | grep -A4 '^screen'` with **ONE** monitor looks like:

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep -A4 '^screen'
screen #0:
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (506x285 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x1ba
```

and with **two** monitors looks like this:

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep -A4 '^screen'
screen #0:
  dimensions:    3280x1080 pixels (865x285 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x1ba
```

If this is indeed the cause of my problems, then how should I add my second monitor?

Comment: You can crop output screenshot with `convert` as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/647272/386622

Comment: My answer is good as-is, but as you mentioned, the issue is maybe elsewhere. In your xrandr command, there are 2 --oputput. Could you remove one and see if you still have a big screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the very useful suggestion from [@Arkadiusz Drabczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3691891/arkadiusz-drabczyk) I wrote a script that works. I thought I would share the solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

# to have at most one instance of this script running...
script_name=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
for pid in $(pidof -x $script_name); do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi 
done

loc="/path/to/folder/"

# take screenshots every minute starting at next minute...
s=$((60 - $(date +%-S)))
sleep "$s"s

while true
do
    f=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    scrot -q 20 "$f".jpg
    n=$(xrandr --listmonitors | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/Monitors: //g")
    if (( n == 2 )); then
    convert -crop 1920x1080 +repage "$f".jpg "$f"_%d.jpg
    mv -t "$loc" "$f"_0.jpg "$f"_1.jpg
    rm "$f".jpg
    else
    mv -t "$loc" "$f".jpg
    fi
    s=$((60 - $(date +%-S)))
    sleep "$s"s
done
```

**NOTES:**

1. The above script does more than what I originally asked for:

   - It ensures at most one instance of this script is running (first code paragraph) which is borrowed from this [stack-overflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213288/killing-the-previous-instances-of-a-script-before-running-the-same-unix-script) post. (As pointed out by [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in the comments this is not a good practice. Please be mindful of it.)
   - It takes screenshot every minute starting at the start of next minute using a bunch of `sleep commands`. This feature could be replaced using [cron-job handler](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cron) if you prefer.
   - The very minimal solution to above question would be `convert -crop 1920x1090 +repage "$f".jpg "$f"_%d.jpg`. (So you are welcome to strip these bloats, if you prefer). I have added the extra bits anticipating typical usage, so that one may use the code as it is.
2. Here is how to do other things, if you want to:

   - You could replace `1920x1080` with whatever is the dimension of your left monitor. You could find these dimensions using `xrandr -q | grep " connected"`.
   - My code is intended for use on a fixed set up where, the left monitor is always `1920x1080`. You are welcome to make it fancier so that it would work with any setup.
   - Again my code is intended for use on a fixed set up with at most 2 monitors. Again you are welcome to generalize to arbitrary number of monitors.
   - A word of advice if you plan to do the above generalizations so that it would work with any setup: Yes you would need `sed/awk/grep` or similar to process the output of `xrandr -q`. But note that `xrandr -q` can be slow step (as noted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150816/how-can-i-lazily-read-output-from-xrandr) and [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41059)). However the output of `xrandr -q` wouldn't change as often. So to make faster code, you could dump the output of `xrandr -q` once, every time it's output would change and use the text from the dump for subsequent operations (as illustrated in this [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538238/267021)) to avoid running `xrandr -q` on every loop.

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Killing other instances of this script with complete abandon is horribly hostile. Just  exit this script with an error message and leave the competitor running.

Comment: This is a matter of taste. You are imposing/ administarting your design aesthetics here.

Comment: These aesthetics have to do with avoiding unpleasant surprises and are reasonably universal. Action at a distance is a problem whether it is caused by `goto`, global variables, or rogue processes killing yours.

Comment: I see. I agree. I would add a note to that effect in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is [MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/).

Installation is quite easy (not need for expensive Python modules):

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user -U mss
```

It will add a new `mss` executable you can call anytime.

For instance, to get a screenshot for each monitor, just type:

```
$ mss
/home/USER/monitor-1.png
/home/USER/monitor-2.png
/home/USER/monitor-3.png
```

If you want to capture only the first monitor:

```
$ mss --monitor 1
/home/USER/monitor-1.png
```

To capture a screenshot of all monitors in one picture (as scrot is doing):

```
$ mss --monitor -1
/home/USER/monitor-0.png
```

As of now, the help man shows:

```
$ mss --help
usage: mss [-h] [-c COORDINATES] [-l {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}] [-m MONITOR]
           [-o OUTPUT] [-q] [-v]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c COORDINATES, --coordinates COORDINATES
                        the part of the screen to capture: top, left, width,
                        height
  -l {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, --level {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
                        the PNG compression level
  -m MONITOR, --monitor MONITOR
                        the monitor to screen shot
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        the output file name
  -q, --quiet           do not print created files
  -v, --version         show program's version number and exit
```